# Where is the changelog  for Ubuntu kernels?

Tags: kernel

Where can I find the `changelog` between versions of the kernel released for Ubuntu 10.04?  Note that I need to find the changelog for 10.04 from an 11.04 system, so if I have to, I can run a VM for this purpose.

"*Why do  I need the kernel changelog?*" you may ask.  I need it because I'm going to package a custom build of the kernel for myself onto a PPA I own, and I need the changelog to show my changes to the kernel in addition to all previous changes done by the Ubuntu developers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The latest version of the kernel for Ubuntu can be seen [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux). See all current changelogs here:

- http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+changelog

That should tell you what changed in each release.

Given that your main aim is to build your own kernel packages though, you might be better off following these guides:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: How to see this changelog with apt-get changelog package? Is anybody knows ?

Answer (score 7):

You could also add the relevant repos for lucid (it will not harm your system, given that the packages have older version number, so are ignored in `dist-upgrade`), update the cache and use the command

```
apt-get changelog linux-image-$version
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer.

Comment: This has less details than the link provided in the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

I find http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges to be more human readable for each Major Kernel change (2.6.31, 2.6.32... 2.6.39)

For individual kernel versions i normally go here:

http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux26Changes

Which shows in a more human readable way what is new, improved or fixed in each kernel version release.

NOTE: Not related to specific Ubuntu kernel releases but as help for kernel news for future Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

@enzotib's answer didn't work for me, but one of the packages which include the kernel version is bound to get the correct report.

You can use this to figure out which one works:

```
$ dpkg -l | awk "\$2 ~ /$(uname -r)/ { print \$2 }" | xargs -n1 -t apt changelog
```

And in my case all except `linux-image-${version}-generic` worked.

```
$ dpkg -l | awk "\$2 ~ /$(uname -r)/ { print \$2 }" 
linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic
linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
linux-modules-5.0.0-23-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-23-generic
```

E.g., `apt changelog linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic`.