# Where can I find the Ubuntu kernel changelogs?

Tags: kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Kernel ChangeLog for Ubuntu Kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55355/finding-kernel-changelog-for-ubuntu-kernels)

I was wondering if there was a specific source that posted Ubuntu's changelogs for their kernel releases. I would like the changelogs because I want to check the changes before updating the kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the package itself (package [linux](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/linux)) you can find these on

- [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions?action=show&redirect=Linux26Changes)
- [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/)

And then there is the Linux Kernel Mailing List ([LLKML.ORG](https://lkml.org/)) where (technical) discussions on the design of, and bugs in the Linux kernel take place.