# Linux kernel release notes

Tags: kernel, 15.04

What is the difference between the Kernel versions `3.19.0-37` and `3.19.0-39`. These kernels are available for Ubuntu version 15.04. Where can I the Kernel version `3.19.0-39` release notes?

Comment: You can look here: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux As answered already in  http://askubuntu.com/questions/55355/where-is-the-changelog-for-ubuntu-kernels

Answer (score 3):

`3.19.0-39` is the update to `0-37`. It was released on the 2<sup>nd</sup> of December 2015 - and there is a newer `0-41` released on the 7<sup>th</sup>.

You can find the change logs [here online](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.19.0-39.44/) or in `/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-3.19.0-39/changelog.Debian.gz/changelog.Debian` on your local machine.

As normal, the kernel is a lot of big fixes etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see the changes is to look into the Ubuntu kernel [git repo](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git)