# Where to find Ubuntu change logs (esp the kernel)

Tags: kernel

Where can I find change logs for various parts of Ubuntu, especially the kernel? I've looked, and I can't find them.

A Software Update dialog just popped up, with the 2nd "linux image" update in 2 days, and the only detail is something like "Bump ABI 5.0.0-20". What does that mean? I'd like to know what changed from -19.

Comment: Terrance's answer with `apt` is a great starting point and probably sufficient for most users (also run `uname -r` on its own to understand the argument to `apt changelog` that you might then choose to play around with). If you need more options see this post/question referring to older versions of Ubuntu, the answers there are still current, - https://askubuntu.com/questions/55355/where-is-the-changelog-for-ubuntu-kernels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `apt changelog`

```
apt changelog linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!