# Block_dump reporting missing from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04

I am trying to monitor what is causing my disks to come out of standby. One of the tools I was using on Ubuntu 20.04 was writing to `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump`, which provided details on what was accessing a disk. However, this appears to be missing on my 22.04 LTS Server install.

Is there something that has replaced this that provide equivalent functionality ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the changelog  for Ubuntu kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55355/where-is-the-changelog-for-ubuntu-kernels)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems that this was removed from the kernel. There is a better alternative though:

```
sudo blktrace -d /dev/sda -a pc -o - | blkparse -i -
```

and then in another terminal

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda
```

to suspend the drive. In the blktrace terminal you'll see the command to suspend and then whatever is trying to access it later on, waking it up:

```
  8,16   8        1     0.000000000 24462  D   N 0 [hdparm]
  8,16  10        1     0.605317187     0  C   N [0]
  8,16   3        1 13730.287432496 742463  D   R 512 [udisksd]
  8,16  11        1 13739.892840047 599559  R   R [0]
  8,16  11        2 13739.901193229   342  R   R [0]
  8,16  11        3 13739.909186805   342  R   R [0]
  8,16  11        4 13739.917183658   342  R   R [0]
```

As you see, in my case it was udisksd (do a search and you'll find dozens of threads complaining that this app is waking up drives)

Please note: modern disks, especially those designed for high availability in data centers may not like spin up/downs frequently and may actually do bettern leaving it on. Study the MTBF ratings for the HDD if it has a separate entry for spinups and operating hours if your case is not obvious (eg backup HDD used once a week). For notebooks an additional concern is that usually a drive that is spinning will do worse in case the notebook is dropped, compared to the case when it is powered off and the drive head in safety position.

Comment: installing blktrace installs also x11 on debian(